# enabling Oracle TDE

Tags: oracle, unix, plsql

We are planning to enable ORACLE TDE in our database for all the tablespaces.

I would like to know what impact it would have on my shell and Perl scripts that run on a client machine. The shell and Perl have username and passwords to connect and execute queries and procedures.  Would it not work if I turn on TDE? will I have to use wallets instead of username and password once I enabled TDE?

Comment: Improved Grammar and typos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TDE should be transparent (hence the "T") to applications that are accessing the data.  The use of wallets etc is more within the scope of the DBA operations for opening/closing the database, and encrypting the data.

Normal application queries should be unimpacted, and user names and passwords are similarly not affected.

There is a very good FAQ on TDE here

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/security/tde-faq-093689.html

Comment: can you tell me how you integrate this with java code , like how i will access the key in my code to encrypt the database column